# Error callback not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a learnunode tutorial, and got stuck at a question so I'd like your help, since the software doesn't provide detailed enough answers.

I'm on a step "make it modular" that asks to separate code into modules. My module is:

```
module.exports = function (dir, filter, err){
    var fs = require("fs");
    var re = new RegExp('\\.' + filter + '$');

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var name = list[i];

            if(name.match(re))
                console.log(list[i]);
        };
    });
}
```

but the tutorial says it's not correct with message:

> Your additional module file:  /home/user/learnunode/submodule.js does
>   not appear to pass back an error received from `fs.readdir()`
>
> Use the following idiomatic Node.js pattern inside your callback to
>   `fs.readdir()`:   if (err)      return callback(err)
>
> ## FAIL

But I am using those lines. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
The calling module is this:
var mod = require('./submodule');

```
var mod = require('./submodule');

var folder = process.argv[2];
var extension = process.argv[3];
mod(folder, extension);
```

Maybe I should've caught the error or declare it and pass to the mod?

Comment: Wearing my guessing hat, but would a semi colon at the end of the return statement help in this case?

Comment: It's usual, if you're not using curly braces to structure your code, to have the `return` on the same line as the `if`. Perhaps it's that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but neither of those changed the result. I will update my question with new code.

Comment: @GruffBunny seemingly little known fact, Javascript does not require the `;` to terminate a line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002234/do-we-need-semicolon-at-the-end

Comment: @JustinWood The suggestion was more targeted towards whatever was parsing the js to give the error message. Nevertheless, it's good practice to add the semi colon otherwise semi colon insertion could cause unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callback` is undefined, so you can't call it like a function. I'm not sure what the correct code is, by I suspect that changing your first line to:

```
module.exports = function (dir, filter, callback){
```

will fix your problem.