# Jquery Datepicker placeholder not showing after blur

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have simple 2 text field. One is normal text and another i have used for datepicker. I want to clear placeholder `onfocus` and show again `onblur` this is following code i am using:

```
$('input,textarea').focus(function(){
    $(this).data('placeholder',$(this).attr('placeholder'))
    console.log($(this).data('placeholder'));
    $(this).attr('placeholder','');
});
$('input,textarea').blur(function(){
    console.log("adding "+$(this).data('placeholder'));
    $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('placeholder'));
});
```

For normal text its working fine but for datepicker text field placeholder not coming after blur. Is there is any solution so that **datepicker text field could behave like simple text field** ?

Try with [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndnxznn3/1/)

Comment: Line 10: $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));

Semicolon missing

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs are you sure its just because of `;`? I don't think so :-(

Comment: Was just a comment on your thing, now looking for options..
A second

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002234/do-we-need-semicolon-at-the-end @PhilAndelhofs

Comment: I know but thanks :D still looking for an easy fix, founded i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two focus events are triggered because of the datepicker. The second time it triggers it gets rid of the property placeholder. So just check for the property before storing in .data(). Something like this should do it

```
$('input,textarea').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('placeholder')) {
        $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).prop('placeholder'))
        $(this).prop('placeholder', '');
    }
});
$('input,textarea').blur(function () {
    if (!$(this).prop('placeholder')) {
        $(this).prop('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
    }
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ndnxznn3/25/**

Comment: Hmmm this is the solution i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an exception in for the date picker, so that the placeholder doesn't get cleared down:

```
$('input:not(#thedate),textarea:not(#thedate)').focus(function(){
```

Comment: Completely wrong i want datepicker placeholder to be cleared and should come back like normal text.