# Perfectly fine JavaScript syntax creating error in Eval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I'm creating a very primitive, online interpreter/compiler in Node.js for multiple languages just for the experience and I've run in to a very odd problem when running JS code.

When a user posts, I take their input, escape it a little, and feed it directly into the command line (terrible practice, I know, but I'll be moving to a new system later that doesn't involve direct CMD) This escapes double quotes and \n, \r, etc.

When getting input, I `child_process.exec` it with the command (yes, I am giving it a callback, but it's a fairly long one that I don't think is necessary to write)

```
let parentResults = cp.exec(`node ./builders/${this.builder}.js "${this.escapedCode}"`);
// First parameter represents the builder to run the user input with
// and escaped code is self-explanatory
```

The builder that handles JS only has one line:

```
eval(process.argv[2]); // Already somewhat-escaped code
```

Now, when I write something like

```
function foo(x) {
  console.log(x);
}

foo(5);
```

I get the correct output in the console of `5`.

But when I do something like

```
let foo = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
}

foo(5);
```

I get an error saying

```
console.log(x); 
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The same thing happens when I use arrow syntax as well. I have no clue what could be tripping it up. Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are missing a `;` after the `}` in the second case. Normally it wouldn't be a problem as javascript interprets the `\n` as the end of the declaration, but you said that you are removing `\n`, so this is why it fails.

Comment: Selected as best answer because I felt your answer gave a better explanation as to code's failure before Stuart's edits.

Answer (score 2):

It is the missing semicolon in the second example that is tripping it up. It should be:

```
let foo = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
};

foo(5);
```

Your builder seems to be removing the newline characters, which would otherwise allow javascript to deal with the absence of a semicolon. (See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002234/do-we-need-semicolon-at-the-end) for more explanation on when js can automatically insert a semicolon.)

Comment: I couldn't think it could be that easy of a mistake. Thanks!